# How to convert nested xml to csv using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xml, csv

I am trying to write a python program that'll take any xml file as input and convert it to a csv file without missing any xml tags/elements. I am open to using any option as long as it's using python.

I tried using xmltodict, json, csv and pandas python modules and was able to read xml and convert it into a dictionary. But I cannot convert this dictionary into a list which can be written to csv file to ensure all xml fields are captured.

My sample xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <tag_1>
    <tag_2>
      <date value="06-30-2023">
        <data>
          <tag_3>val_3</tag_3>
          <tag_4>val_4</tag_4>
          <tag_5>val_5_1 &amp; val_5_2</tag_5>
          <tag_6>-0.157</tag_6>
        </data>
        <data>
          <tag_3>val_3</tag_3>
          <tag_4>val_4_2</tag_4>
          <tag_5>val_5_1</tag_5>
          <tag_6>-0.173</tag_6>
        </data>
      </date>
    </tag_2>
    <tag_7>
      <date value="06-30-2023">
        <data><tag_3>val_3</tag_3><tag_4>val_4</tag_4><tag_5>val_5_1 &amp; val_5_2</tag_5><tag_6>-0.157</tag_6>
        </data>
        <data><tag_3>val_3</tag_3><tag_4>val_4_2</tag_4><tag_5>val_5_1</tag_5><tag_6>-0.173</tag_6>
        </data>
      </date>
    </tag_7>
  </tag_1>
```

After reading above xml, I am able to convert it to dictionary:

```py
{'tag_1': 
  {'tag_2': 
    {'date': 
      {'@value': '06-30-2023', 
       'data': [{'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1 & val_5_2', 'tag_6': '-0.157'}, 
                {'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4_2', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1', 'tag_6': '-0.173'}
           ]
      }
     }, 
   'tag_7': 
    {'date': 
      {'@value': '06-30-2023', 
       'data': [{'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1 & val_5_2', 'tag_6': '-0.157'}, 
                {'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4_2', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1', 'tag_6': '-0.173'}
               ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My expected output (in csv file) is:

```
tag_1,tag_2,date,data,tag_3,tag_4,tag_5,tag_6
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
```

What I have tried so far:

```py
import xmltodict
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("file_01.xml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as xml_fh:
    str_xml = xml_fh.read()

print(f"str_xml={type(str_xml)}={str_xml}")

dict_xml = xmltodict.parse(str_xml)
print(f"dict_xml={type(dict_xml)}={dict_xml}")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_xml, orient='index')
df.to_csv('file_01.csv', index = False)
```

The actual result that I am getting is:

```
tag_2,tag_7
"{'date': {'@value': '06-30-2023', 'data': [{'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1 & val_5_2', 'tag_6': '-0.157'}, {'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4_2', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1', 'tag_6': '-0.173'}]}}","{'date': {'@value': '06-30-2023', 'data': [{'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1 & val_5_2', 'tag_6': '-0.157'}, {'tag_3': 'val_3', 'tag_4': 'val_4_2', 'tag_5': 'val_5_1', 'tag_6': '-0.173'}]}}"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pd.json_normalize()` to flatten the dictionary created from the XML. However, since records reside under two different keys: `tag_2` and `tag_7`, we need to loop over those particular tags to get all the records, then concatenate the dataframes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict

with open("file_01.xml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as xml_fh:
    str_xml = xml_fh.read()

dict_xml = xmltodict.parse(str_xml)

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.json_normalize(
            dict_xml, 
            record_path=['tag_1', tag, 'date', 'data'],            # path to record list
            meta=[['tag_1', tag, 'date', '@value']])               # path to date
        .pipe(lambda x: x.rename(columns={x.columns[-1]: 'date'})) # rename date column
        .assign(tag_1='tag_1', tag_2=tag, data='data')             # add meta columns
        for tag in ('tag_2', 'tag_7')                              # loop over tags
    ]
)[['tag_1', 'tag_2', 'date', 'data', 'tag_3', 'tag_4', 'tag_5', 'tag_6']]
df.to_csv('file_01.csv', index=False)
```

This creates the following CSV file:

```
tag_1,tag_2,date,data,tag_3,tag_4,tag_5,tag_6
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,data,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
```

---

Perhaps a more maintainable way is to normalize the relevant sub-dictionary under each level 2 key. Note that in the code below, the `record_path` and `meta` paths are no longer lists.

```py
def flatten_dict(dict_xml, level_2_tags):
    df = (
        pd.concat([
            pd.json_normalize(dict_xml['tag_1'][tag]['date'], 'data', '@value')
            .assign(tag_2=tag)
            for tag in level_2_tags
        ])
        .rename(columns={'@value': 'date'})
        .assign(tag_1='tag_1', data='data')
        .get(['tag_1', 'tag_2', 'date', 'data', 'tag_3', 'tag_4', 'tag_5', 'tag_6'])
    )
    return df

# test run
flatten_dict(dict_xml, ['tag_2'])           # when there is only tag_2 in level=2

flatten_dict(dict_xml, ['tag_2', 'tag_7'])  # when there are 2 tags in level=2
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer @cottontail. It works and I am evaluating it. Out of curiosity, would you mind sharing the version of solution in case if we didn't have tag_2 and tag_7? Let's say if there was just tag_2? I am also checking if I can get separate xml for tag_2 and tag_7 as the solution I am building needs to be reusable for different xmls.

Comment: I tried `df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(dict_xml['tag_1']['tag_2']['date'], 'data', '@value')])[['tag_1', 'tag_2', 'date', 'data', 'tag_3', 'tag_4', 'tag_5', 'tag_6']]` but getting error `KeyError: "['tag_1', 'tag_2', 'date', 'data'] not in index"`. Am I missing something obvious or syntax wise?

Comment: Thank you a ton :) Solution with function for both formats of xml worked like charm for me. I am going to use this and parameterize it as much as possible (Let user provide tag names and use those). I'll post update here once my testing is done.

Answer (score 1):

Given the custom format, it looks like the best option is to use a nested list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'tag_1': k1, 'tag_2': k2, k3: d3['@value'], **d4}
                   for k1, d1 in dict_xml.items()
                   for k2, d2 in d1.items()
                   for k3, d3 in d2.items()
                   for d4 in d3['data']])
```

Output:

```
   tag_1  tag_2        date  tag_3    tag_4              tag_5   tag_6
0  tag_1  tag_2  06-30-2023  val_3    val_4  val_5_1 & val_5_2  -0.157
1  tag_1  tag_2  06-30-2023  val_3  val_4_2            val_5_1  -0.173
2  tag_1  tag_7  06-30-2023  val_3    val_4  val_5_1 & val_5_2  -0.157
3  tag_1  tag_7  06-30-2023  val_3  val_4_2            val_5_1  -0.173
```

CSV output:

```
# df.to_csv('file_01.csv', index=False)

tag_1,tag_2,date,tag_3,tag_4,tag_5,tag_6
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_2,06-30-2023,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,val_3,val_4,val_5_1 & val_5_2,-0.157
tag_1,tag_7,06-30-2023,val_3,val_4_2,val_5_1,-0.173
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer @mozway. It works and I am evaluating it. Out of curiosity, would you mind sharing the version of solution in case if we didn't have tag_2 and tag_7? Let's say if there was just tag_2? I am also checking if I can get separate xml for tag_2 and tag_7 as the solution I am building needs to be reusable for different xmls.

Comment: If you didn't have `tag_7` you could use `{k1: k1, k2: k2, k3: d3['@value'], **d4}`, but it's difficult to comment on how to generalize without knowing more examples ;)